# Change order of users on Gnome login screen?

Tags: gnome, users, login

My machine has 3 users: A, B, and C.

On the Gnome login screen, they display as B, A, C. That appears to be in order of most frequent login.

How do I change the order of the login screen to either be fixed, or alphabetical, rather than frequency based?

- GNOME Shell 3.38.4
- Pop_OS 21.04

Comment: For context, there is a similar unanswered Ubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/q/810480